# How do I reset/permit a previously denied java applet?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8, java-applet

I have a customer with a small problem. A few weeks ago when he get on a web page for his job, he clicked ***denied*** on the popup window asking for permission for downloading and running a Java applet.

Since then, he realizes that he needs that applet.

To reset the permission of applet so he can authorize it, I tried to clear IE and Java cache without success. I Googled it and searched on superuser.com but I've found nothing (lot of Mac but nothing on Windows). I know a Windows reinstall would resolve the case but I found it excessive for this problem.

So my question is: How do I reset (or clear) the permission for the Java applet?

Comment: The current version of Java has a Control Panel Applet that controls all settings for Java.  You can reset the configuration of Java on the system using the applet.  This applet does not exist before Java 7 Update 10.

Comment: @Ramhound: "This applet does not exist before Java 7 Update 10." The Java Control Panel applet *wasn't* introduced with JRE/JDK 7u10.

Comment: The last update in our environnent is Java 6 update 17....ya I know, we're a bit late! Therefore I doesn't have that "Applet Control Panel" and I can't update Java because of network restriction.

Comment: There's been a Control Panel applet since [Java 5](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cihs.png) and perhaps even earlier, so if you don't see it there's something amiss. If `Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javacpl.exe` exists, try running it.

Comment: I've checked the control panel and there's no options for applets, and since I've cleared temp file there is no applet remaining on the computer. I've also tried a "reset settings" on IE 8 without success...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To configure Java security in Internet Explorer:**

1. Start Internet Explorer, and then click **Internet Options** on the **Tools** menu.
2. In the **Internet Options** dialog box, click the **Security** tab.
3. There are four security zones on the Security page:

   - Internet
   - Local intranet
   - Trusted Sites
   - Restricted Sites

Select the zone on which you want to change the Java security settings.

4. In the **Security level** for this zone frame, click **Custom Level**. In Internet Explorer version 4.x, click **Custom Level**, and then click **Settings**.
5. View the **Microsoft VM** section (the **Java** section in Internet Explorer 4.x.)
6. In the list of Java Permissions under the **Microsoft VM**, click **Custom**.
7. Click **Java Custom Settings**.
8. Click the **View Permissions** tab to view the current Java permissions. The Java permissions are grouped in three main categories:

   - Permissions Given to Unsigned Content
     Unsigned Java applets that request these permissions can run without bringing up a user prompt.
   - Permissions That Signed Content Are Allowed
     Signed Java applets that requests these permissions can run without user prompting.
   - Permissions That Signed Content Are Denied
     Signed Java applets are denied these permissions.
9. Click the **Edit Permissions** tab. Select the option you need for more exact control over Java permissions for the zone. If you do not want to keep the settings that you have made, you can click the **Reset** button to reset permissions to:

   - Saved permissions
   - High Security
   - Medium Security
   - Low Security
     Click **OK**, and then click **OK** again.

**Notes**
Use caution when you adjust Java permissions. Some Java-based programs may not work properly after you change permissions. Some changes to Java permissions can make your computer liable to security breaches by hackers. Microsoft recommends that you do not change the default permissions unless you have a specific purpose for doing so.

Comment: I've tried resetting security settings to default and even turning them to low without success.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair: It would have been nice to have given credit to the source [Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315674).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to [reset Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737).

Comment: I've tried it. No success.

Comment: Have a look at this [expanded procedure](http://www.ehow.com/how_6911367_fix-java-plug_in-error.html). While removing java make sure that its folders in "Program Files" and in "Program Files (x86)" are removed.